# Drupal Commerce on Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

Will Drupal Commerce run only on Drupal 7 core,

and not support Backward core versions Like Drupal 6 ?

Comment: A popular ecommerce module for Drupal 6 is [Übercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart/).

Comment: But Ubercart is not having as many e-com features like Commerce module.. I'll end up writing code for most of the features i want if i continue in Drupal 6 + Ubercart version

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: It won't be backported to D6.

Drupal commerce is based (strongly dependent) on drupal 7 entity system. Is not possible to backport it to Drupal 6. It is not in commerce goals, either.

BTW: There is a [Q+A site specially for drupal questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/). Consider posting your Drupal related questions there.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks .. will have to evaluate how much effort shall be required to Upgrade 6.14 to Version 7

Comment: @mjs Moving to D7 is worth it. Consider checking the answer :) Thanks!

Comment: was just waiting for some more thoughts before checking it :).. We are having kinda stable site with drupal + ubercart .. now we wanted some more e-com features hence looking at commerce module or something lyk magento or opencart .. just want to be clear with all the options in hand before making a major change

Comment: @mjs that is great. But the question is already answered on it's current incarnation. Consider editing it to include more options. Cheers. Regarding the rest of your comment consider that D7+Commerce is a great enhancement, but migrations are always tricky, also to other systems.

Comment: but i guess support for drupal + commerce shall be less as it has just got out in the market ..

Comment: @mjs Drupal + Commerce is quite new, you're right, but growing quickly. Right now is the main choice for ecommerce with drupal and is builded on top of the power and flexibility of Drupal 7 entity system and views. Commerce guys and Acquia (two big Drupal shop companies) are giving support for commerce module. There are many more. Sure that you can find any close to you. There is many documentation and tutorials. I recommend you start with http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart. A D7 distro. Good Luck!

Comment: i have gone through the commerce kickstart .. i absolutely love the way checkout has been handled now .. thanks for your views

Comment: @mjs your are welcome. Glad to be of any help :) Check also http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-commerce?sort=newest

Answer (score 3):

http://www.drupalcommerce.org is a great website for anything Drupal commerce. It also has a Q-A section.

Comment: Correct official link! You can also refer the following to learn Drupal commerce installation on localhost with XAMPP: http://studyopedia.com/drupal/drupal-installation/